# "No multiboot header found" with minimal kernel

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, osdev

I build a simple OS with three files, but get a ogg problem, the files are here:

loader.s

```
.extern kernel_main

.global _start

.set MB_ALIGN,    1<<0
.set MB_MEMINFO,  1<<1
.set MB_MAGIC,    0x1BADB002
.set MB_FLAGS,    MB_ALIGN | MB_MEMINFO
.set MB_CHECKSUM, - (MB_MAGIC + MB_FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .align 4
    .long MB_MAGIC
    .long MB_FLAGS
    .long MB_CHECKSUM

.section .bss
    .align 16
    stack_bottom:
        .skip 4096
    stack_top:

.section .text
    _start:
        mov $stack_top, %esp

        call kernel_main

        hang:
            cli
            hlt
            jmp hang

.size _start, . - _start
```

and kernel.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>


const int a = 10;

void kernel_main()
{
    uint8_t* video = (uint8_t*) 0xB8000;
    const char* hello = "Hello World! From MYOS";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        video[2 * i] = hello[i];
        video[2 * i + 1] = 0x07;
    }
}
```

and linker.ld

```
ENTRY(_start);

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M;

    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
    }



    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.text)
    }


    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }


    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }


    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

and I compile these code:

```
i686-elf-gcc -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -g -c start.s -o start.o

i686-elf-gcc -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -g -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -g -T linker.ld start.o kernel.o -o mykernel.elf -lgcc
```

I run this kernel, but got no multiboot header found.
if I modify kernel.c to:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>


const int a = 10; // Just add this line.

void kernel_main()
{
    uint8_t* video = (uint8_t*) 0xB8000;
    const char* hello = "Hello World! From MYOS";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        video[2 * i] = hello[i];
        video[2 * i + 1] = 0x07;
    }
}
```

Its work! Why?

Comment: add multiboot to text section

Comment: Both `kernel.c` variants you show contain that `const int a = 10;` line.

Comment: As for your problem, you have two `.rodata` sections in the output file. Guess what happens with them (take a look at the generated ELF file).

Comment: out of curiosity what version of the GCC elf cross compiler are you using (and cross compiled version of binutils)? And are you absolutely sure the linker script, the assembly files, the C files and the commands used to link/compile you are *exactly* as what you are showing here.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty Add multiboot to text section it work , but here https://wiki.osdev.org/User:Zesterer/Bare_Bones the multiboot in rodata section. I am very confused.

Comment: check the hexdump of both the binaries, and see whats the difference? also check how the header data is layed out in two format. let us know the difference if you find.

Comment: In order to tell you exactly what i happening what would be useful is to have you add the output of the command `objdump -x mykernel.elf`of the version that doesn't work to your question. The multiboot header won't necessarily be found if it is beyond the first 8kb of the ELF file (and/or it is not aligned to a 4 byte boundary). Most likely when it doesn't work there is a likely 8kb of section data/code/meta data being placed before the multiboot header.

Comment: Depending on your platform you may have to use `i686-elf-objdump -x mykernel.elf` if you are in fact using a cross compiled environment.